# junit test with android

Tags: android

I Want to perform junit test on android Activity

i have activity name Thmnail.java in Thumb Project
Now i create the test project called ThumbTest and make the testclass called ThmnailTest 
Now when i called the method of the Thmnail from the ThmnailTest

getSetTagName(tagId,R.id.edTag11);

the above called the tagid i m pass but the R.id.edTag11 is the AutoCompleteTextView is in the thmnail it can give the error

android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2802)
at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:607)
at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:633)
at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2505)
at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5115)
at android.widget.TextView.invalidateCursor(TextView.java:3625)
at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:6221)
at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:6346)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:906)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:611)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:514)
at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:74)
at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:85)
at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:497)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2676)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
at com.avisun.fileaway.FileawayThumbnail.getSetTagName(FileawayThumbnail.java:276)
at com.avisun.fileaway.FileawayThumbnail.getAutoTextFillwithTag(FileawayThumbnail.java:245)
at com.avisun.fileAway.test.FileawayThumbnailTest.testAutotext(FileawayThumbnailTest.java:51)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:204)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:194)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:186)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:520)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1447)

Answer (score 0):

You have to run all UI operation on the UI thread.  You're trying to call `getSetTagName` on the JUnit thread.  Try using [Activity.runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to call `getSetTagName`.

Next you'll have to deal with the synchronization issues of having a mutli-threaded test.